# How to call a variable from multiple private methods?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I basically want to call an object from a private method within the same class. How do I go about doing this?

If i have

```
  Private void method1(){

         object a = new Object();
         object b = new Object();
  } 





  Private void method2(){

         // call object a and b here
           i.e.   a.Children.Add(tb);
                  b.Children.Add(tb);
  }
```

Comment: you cannot, you have to have them as variables in the class scope

Comment: Your example is confusing.  You have 2 methods named the same thing with no overloading taking place.  That would go boom.  And you don't "call objects", you call methods on objects.  Please make your question more clear.

Comment: you can't have two methods with the same signature.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with WPF?

Comment: Sorry I meant method3. I have changed it

Comment: I think you are really asking how can you return a object from one method to another?? If so edit your question to make it clear that is what you want.

Comment: Im new to programming. How do i go about doing this?

Comment: Declare `ObjectWithChildren a, b;` in the containg class. Initialize `a,b` in `Method1`,  `a = new ObjectWithChildren();` and `Method2`, `b = new ObjectWithChildren();`. In `Method3`, `a` and `b` will be available, as they are declared in the scope of the class (but make sure they are not `null`, as this could happen if the previous methods are not called).

Comment: google returning a object from a method...google is a programmer best friend.

Answer (score 1):

The variable is only in scope within that method.  You cannot access it outside of the function it is defined in.  Perhaps more information about the problem you are trying to solve will help yield a useful answer.

Comment: How can I access variables outside the scope of the method? maybe setting the visibility to public?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're trying to achieve here.  Try to provide more code.  You can have a class member variable that can be accessed by all methods in that class.